# ThreadLocal get() returning null sometimes after spring boot upgrade from 2.1.4 to 3.4.3

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, thread-local

This is the code:

```
public class ContextManagerImpl implements ContextManager {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Context> ctx = new ThreadLocal<Context>();
    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        if(ctx.get() == null) {
            ctx.set(new Context("", ""));   // Dummy context. This should never happen
        }
        return ctx.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(Context context){
        ctx.set(context);                            // Verified context passed is never null or blank 
    }

    @Override
    public void end() {
        if(ctx!= null) {
            ctx.remove();
        }
    }
}

public final class Context implements Serializable {
    private String s1;
    private String s2;
}
```

There are 2 threads which are using this class with different threadlocal context. It works fine most of the time, however sometimes even when begin() sets the value in ctx properly, getContext() returns dummy context.
I suspect there is a race condition somewhere which is causing this but given that threadlocal set() and get() are threadsafe and initialisation of ctx is done during declaration this should never happen.
Note: I have upgraded spring boot to 3.4.3 but still using JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

> ThreadLocal get() returning null sometimes after spring boot upgrade from 2.1.4 to 3.4.3

If Spring guarantees that `begin(...)` is called before `getContext()`, then it sounds to me like a one thread is doing the call to `begin(...)` method and another thread is calling `getContext()`.  If this is the case the `getContext()` will return null.

`ThreadLocal` is designed to provide a *different* context for each thread.  Is that what you want?  I don't fully understand your wiring but I'm suspicious of your use of `ThreadLocal`.  What are the spring boot guarantees around threads?

I suspect that you should instead just make it a `volatile` field:

```
 private static volatile Context ctx; // maybe set to new Context("", "");
 // this should be called by spring boot
 @Override
 public Context begin(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
 }
 public Context getContext() {
    return ctx;
 }
```

If you are worried about some race conditions if multiple instances of your `ContextManagerImpl` are being initialized with the same context then you could use an `AtomicReference` instead:

```
 // may want to initialize with a dummy context
 private static AtomicReference <Context> ctxRef = new AtomicReference();
 // this should be called by spring boot
 @Override
 public Context begin(Context ctx) {
    ctxRef.compareAndSet(null, ctx);
 }
 public Context getContext() {
    return ctxRef.get();
 }
```

Comment: Yes it is guaranteed that begin() is called before getContext(). And yes I want each thread to get a different context. If I make variable volatile or AtomicReference then both threads won't have different copies. Problem is that for a thread, even if begin() is called to set the context, getContext() is returning null sometimes. Given that thread is designed to provide a different context for each thread, both threads shouldn't interfere with each other. Not sure what I am missing. Wondering if its because of spring boot 3.4.3 and jdk 8 compatibility ?

Comment: If thread1 calls begin to set the context and then thread 2 calls getContext() it will get null right @pankajsachan?  I really don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry @Gray If I was not clear before but both threads will call begin() before calling getContext() and hence there shouldn't be null.

Comment: Are you sure @pankajsachan that each and every thread that will call `getContext()` will call `begin(...)` first? I suspect this is not the case because you are getting a null. If you are getting a null then your code is not being called like you suspect. Plain and simple.

Comment: to give more details, when a Grpc request comes, in the interceptor I am calling `begin(...)` and then during processing of request in grpc server implementation class I am calling `getContext(...)` to fetch details like header etc which I have set in `begin(...)`. 

I did more reading and found that it is not guaranteed that the grpc request and response will be done in same thread and hence it is possible that when grpc request comes as part of thread X, `begin(...)` is called in that thread and processing/response using `getContext(...)` is done in thread Y? Just a theory though.